# Parsing elements from a markdown file in python 3

Tags: python, markdown, multimarkdown

How might I get a list of elements from a markdown file in python 3?  I'm specifically interested in getting a list of all images and links (along with relevant information like alt-text and link text) out of a markdown file.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349951/parse-and-traverse-elements-from-a-markdown-file) Is some prior art in this area, but it is almost exactly 2 years old at this point, and I expect that the landscape has changed a bit.

Bonus points if the parser you come up with supports multimarkdown.

Comment: @coralv : I've looked into regex to extract the links, but run into the problem that I really need a push down automaton for that, in order to account for arbitrary nested brackets.  Mostly I'm looking for a library solution before I build a parser.

Comment: Markdown itself hasn't changed in over a decade, so I'd say the linked question and answers are pretty up-to-date.

Answer (score 11):

If you take advantage of two Python packages, `pypandoc` and `panflute`, you could do it quite pythonically in a few lines ([sample code](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute-filters/blob/master/filters/extract_urls.py)):

Given a text file `example.md`, and assuming you have Python 3.3+ and already did `pip install pypandoc panflute`, then place the sample code in the same folder and run it from the shell or from e.g. IDLE.

```
import io
import pypandoc
import panflute

def action(elem, doc):
    if isinstance(elem, panflute.Image):
        doc.images.append(elem)
    elif isinstance(elem, panflute.Link):
        doc.links.append(elem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pypandoc.convert_file('example.md', 'json')
    doc = panflute.load(io.StringIO(data))
    doc.images = []
    doc.links = []
    doc = panflute.run_filter(action, prepare=prepare, doc=doc)

    print("\nList of image URLs:")
    for image in doc.images:
        print(image.url)
```

The steps are:

1. Use `pypandoc` to obtain a json string that contains the AST of the markdown document
2. Load it into `panflute` to create a Doc object (panflute requires a stream so we use StringIO)
3. Use the `run_filter` function to iterate over every element, and extract the Image and Link objects.
4. Then you can print the urls, alt text, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "AST"?

Comment: AST = Abstract Syntax Tree. This is Pandoc's internal representation of a document. It can be exported into JSON which is then read by panflute to create a Python object representing the document.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the markdown into html with [Python-Markdown](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown), and then extract what you want from the html document using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which makes extracting images and links very straightforward.

This might seem like a complicated pipeline, but it's certainly easier and more robust than for instance writing an ad hoc markdown parser using regular expressions. These modules are battle tested and efficient.

Comment: Python-Markdown uses ElementTree internally and has an extensive Extension API. You may be able to interrupt the parser and loop over the ElementTree to extract your elements and skip a few steps. But that would be bending things in ways they were not really intended, so parsing the HTML output is probably going to give more reliable results.

Comment: Python-Markdown also has an extensive number of extensions (both [included](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/index.html#officially-supported-extensions) and [third-party](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions)) available so you should be able to get most, if not all, of MultiMarkdown's features. And if there's a missing feature you really care about, you can [write your own extension](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Tutorial:-Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example of [@Håken Lid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946248/1910555):

```
import requests
from markdown import markdown
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StackExchange/Stacks/develop/README.md'
html = markdown(requests.get(url).text, output_format="html5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    print(img['src'])
```

Output:

- https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/actions/workflows/main.yml/badge.svg?branch=develop
- https://img.shields.io/npm/v/@stackoverflow/stacks.svg