# Match text between parenthesis that end with .md

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the text inside the parenthesis where the text ends with `.md` using a regex (if you know another way you can say it) in python.

Original string:
`[Romanian (Romania)](books/free-programming-books-ro.md)`

Expected result:
`books/free-programming-books-ro.md`

Comment: Do note that there are markdown libraries that will parse this syntax for you. I'm not saying it *can't* be done with a regex; just that it's not always the tool you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse and traverse elements from a Markdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349951/parse-and-traverse-elements-from-a-markdown-file)

Comment: Is your question is: *How do I get the links in markdown string*?

Comment: @SuperStormer no

Comment: @balderman yes, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re
s = '[Romanian (Romania)](books/free-programming-books-ro.md)'
result = re.findall(r'[^\(]+\.md(?=\))',s)

['books/free-programming-books-ro.md']
```